# Springboot SSO, there are some strange redirections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to implement my own SSO server using springboot 1.5.3 and thymeleaf client app for testing it.

But there occurred a problem with using authorization_code flow for client app.
 I thought that maybe something in server configuration is wrong, which is why I tried to use postman for getting token and it worked perfectly.

---

Case which doesn't work is:

I try to open page which is secured.
 Let's say that 8080 is port of Authorization server and 8081 of client app.

So as i read about authorization_code flow it should work like that:
1. Open securedPage (8081) 
3. Redirects to login page of authorization server (8080)
3. You write your credentials.
4. Redirects you to your page(8081) along with code.
5. Send request with code for token. (/oauth/token)
6. You get redirected to your website with token.

But in my case it works:
1. Open securedPage (8081)
**2. Redirects to XYZ(8081)**
3. Redirects to login page of authorization server (8080)
4. You write your credentials.
5. **Redirects you to XYZ(8081)** along with code.
6. Error page shows up

XYZ = page under path /login of client app.

What is strange is that there is nothing under this path. And in browser i can see only Whitelabel Error Page
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token

**Authorization server app configuration:**

**Authorization server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter 
{
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("clientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "client_credentials",     "authorization_code", "implicit")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .autoApprove(true)
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8081/login");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(
            AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}
```

**Web security:**

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
```

**Client app configuration:**

**Web configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/index**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

So my two biggest questions are:

Why it redirects me through login page of client app (WHICH DOESN'T EXIST), instead of redirecting me straight to login page of authorization server?

Why i'm getting error message about getting access token, while i was only redirected for getting authorization code? What's more, that succceeded, because on this error page i have code in parameters.

**UPDATE #1**

Error was due to property of client app

security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form

if it is

security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=header

it works correctly, but it still doesn't answer why it is redirected to :8081/login and then to :8080/login instead of just to :8080/login?

Comment: You configured: `.redirectUris("http://localhost:8081/login")`. Why do you think it should redirect to a diffrent URL than you configured?

Comment: Also show your application.properties/yml with your configuration.

Comment: You were right, there was a property with wrong value;/

Comment: About redirectUris, if it is other value than "http://localhost:8081/login" i get something like 'Invalid redirect:     http://localhost:8081/login does not match one of the registered values: [SOMETHING]' and i think it works correctly. Isn't it rather question why client app tries to redirect through "http://localhost:8081/login"?